# Crear bot Telegram que responda a comandos PHP

Tags: php, api, hosting, telegram, telegram-bot

He intentado leyendo la API de Telegram y lo máximo que he conseguido es hacer que una URL funcione pero no consigo entender cómo hacer que responda a los comandos, no entiendo la documentación oficial. Si alguien me puede explicar cómo hacerlo o conoce alguna guía en español que tenga ejemplos le agradeceré ya que las que he visto están carentes de información útil y de poco sirven, he visto un ejemplo en Github y tampoco me queda claro leyendo el código como funciona.

PD: ¿Se puede hacer funcionar un bot de manera local sin internet? En la documentación de la API de telegram me parece haber leído algo sobre esto.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones y/o recomendaciones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Editado, ¿ya se puede volver a abrir la pregunta o tengo que crear otra?

Comment: La pregunta como notas no esta cerrada, ayudaría a mejorar tu publicación que expongas eso que hayas intentado y que le digas a la comunidad exactamente que es lo que no ha funcionado, de esa manera los demás tienen un punto de arranque definido para ayudar